# How does one find GPUs that use UEFI GOP instead of legacy VBIOS?

Tags: graphics-card, bios, uefi, gop

I have a Mac Pro 4,1 which uses UEFI and has no legacy BIOS support. I'd like to purchase a graphics card which uses UEFI GOP by default instead of Legacy VBIOS since, otherwise, I won't see my boot screen when macOS boots.

How does one find UEFI-ready cards? This isn't usually an advertised feature of a card (I've found one card which advertises that it's UEFI-ready). There are many GPU comparison sites, but none seem to list UEFI support on cards.

Please note:

- This is not a shopping question where I'm asking you to tell me which card to buy--I'm asking *how to determine* which cards support a feature using existing resources on the internet. The answer to this question will still be applicable many years to come.
- This is not a Mac-only question. This applies to anyone looking for a UEFI ready card. Perhaps they want to enable secure boot or fast boot on their PC.
- I know UEFI-compatibility is really determined by what's in the option ROM on the card--and this is programmed by the specific card vendor (i.e. Gigabyte, PNY, EVGA, etc), and that one may re-flash (in some cases using a software utility and in others using an EEPROM programmer) a card with a UEFI-ready ROM image (or send the card to someone who will do this for you for $200).

Some ideas I've thought of:

- Call each vendor and ask which of their cards are UEFI-ready. Since the answer probably isn't part of their call-center script, I'm not hopeful.
- Search though troves of forum posts from various dates looking for people who've experimented with various cards.
- Try to find option-ROM images online that people have posted and start dissecting them looking for UEFI GOP firmware sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/what-vid-cards-have-uefi-gop-support.370375/ Going by this discussion, NVidia GPUs of the 7xx Series and AMD 4xx Series or newer should support UEFI boot out of the box. Some older cards(i.e. GTX670) had enough ROM space and got updates to an UEFI compatible BIOS.
So if you buy anything that's not older than those you're fine except maybe some special server cards.